Word shows Print Preview but won't send anything to any printer, even a PDF writer
I edit or create a document in Word. I check the print preview which looks fine. When I select Print I just return to the editing view. It's not a printer problem because:

the printer works with Excel.
the effect is the same when trying to print to a Doro PDF writer.

Have I accidentally changed some setting by accident? Perhaps by hitting an unwitting control key?

Please provide as much information as possible about what you are doing, what you are seeing, and what you expect to see.

Repair install? Does print preview show up? Does Event Viewer show anything? Your question needs a lot more information added by you in order for us to begin to guess at what the problem, and solution, may be. Please EDIT your post to add this information.

If something went wrong with the Office installation, you could:

Repair Office : In Control Panel > Programs and Features, right-click
"Microsoft 365" (or "Microsoft Office") and select "Change".
If this doesn't fix the problem, the big hammer is to uninstall
and reinstall Office.

